# Converting from int[] to list<int> : Any better way

Tags: c++, arrays, list, c++11, vector

I have an integer array as shown:

```
int ia[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

I want to convert it to a `list<int>` and a `vector<int>`. The obvious way that comes to my mind is iterating over the array, and add the elements to the `list<int>` and `vector<int>`:

```
for (auto val: ia) {
    ilist.push_back(val);
    ivec.push_vack(val);
}
```

I just wanted to know, whether there is any other way, probably any available library function?

Comment: As an aside, `std::list` is very rarely the right container.  While at first glance it looks like "the sequential container you should use when you only need iteration", it is actually "the sequential container you should use when you need iterators to persist long-term, or where you do orders of magnitude more insert/deletes in the middle than you do iteration".  It is crippled in both performance and features compared to `std::vector` -- it uses more memory and is slower.

Comment: Thanks @yakk for the invaluable advice. Will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a two-iterator constructor:

```
std::list<int> ilist(std::begin(ia), std::end(ia));
std::vector<int> ivec(std::begin(ia), std::end(ia));
```

If you don't have C++11 support for `std::begin` and `std::end`, you can use

```
std::list<int> ilist(ia, ia + 6);
```

where in real code you would aim to provide an array length function instead of using `6` explicitly.

Better still, you could role out your own `begin` and `end` function templates, for example

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
T* my_end( const T (&a)[N] )
{
  return &a[N];
}
```

**Edit** here's an array length function template:

```
template< class T, size_t N >
std::size_t size( const T (&)[N] )
{
  return N;
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza. Gosh. I was looking for exactly this. Just didn't know how to get an iterator for the built-in array. Thanks :) Will wait for some other options, before accepting it.

Comment: @juanchopanza I suggest you use `ia + sizeof(ia) / sizeof(ia[0])` instead of a hard-coded length.

Comment: @RohitJain, This works for any container. You're not going to find better. The only real shorter way is something like `auto ivec = contFromArray<std::vector<int>>(ia);`, but I see little point.

Comment: @chris. Actually, I knew this way out for conversion between `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc. But forgot how to get the iterators for the built-in arrays. This seems to be the most convenient way for now, until I learn more about templates, and all. Thanks :)

Comment: @juanchopanza You're missing an ampersand in `my_end`'s return statement

Comment: There is a use for writing your own `my_end` and `my_begin` even post C++11 -- the "proper" way to call `std::begin` is by `using std::begin; begin(c);` so that you do ADL that matches how `for( : )` loops work.  In many contexts, doing that two-step dance is annoying: so I tend to have a begin/end helper that does it for me in one step.